# Inverted Pyramid in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to get an inverted pyramid with the code given below. Similar code worked for an upright pyramid but the tweaks dont seem to work for an inverted pyramid.

Tried tweaking the statements a lot but with no luck.

```
    def pym(rows):
      result = ''
      for i in range(rows):
        row = ''
        row += '#' * (i-1)
        row += '*' * (2 * (rows-i) + 1)
        row += '#' * (i-1)
        result += row + '\n'
      return result
    print (pym(4))
```

## expected output

```
*******
#*****#
##***##
###*###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop condition is slightly incorrect, the loop should be corrected to `for i in range(1,rows+1):` instead of `for i in range(rows):`, and then your code works perfectly.

```
def pym(rows):
    result = ''

    #Corrected the range
    for i in range(1,rows+1):
        row = ''
        row += '#' * (i-1)
        row += '*' * (2 * (rows-i) + 1)
        row += '#' * (i-1)
        result += row + '\n'
    return result

print (pym(4))
```

The output is then

```
*******
#*****#
##***##
###*###
```

As you can see, starting from `i=0` instead of `i=1` causes issues with the row variable, e.g. using `i = 0` in the first two expressions of your for loop, the `row` looks as below

```
In [21]: row = ''                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [22]: row += '#' * -1                                                                                                                                                                                

In [23]: row                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[23]: ''
```

Also since you only iterate till `rows-1`, You end up not getting the final pyramid as well.

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic way could be to use `str.center`:

```
def pym(rows):
    n = rows*2
    res = ''
    for i in reversed(range(1,n,2)):
        res += (('*'* i).center(n-1, '#')) + '\n'
    return res
```

Output:

```
print(pym(4))
*******
#*****#
##***##
###*###
```

Comment: There is a `str.center` Never seen this function before, Thanks @Chris +1 :)

Comment: That was something cool. It is something I have never come across. Thanks @Chris for this new insight.

Comment: Glad to provide the new insight XD